# Bitlocker USB-Key and harddrive stolen, data still secure?

Tags: windows, bitlocker, tpm

my Laptop without TPM was stolen. The USB-Key was connected to the device. Can the robber with the usb-key access my data? I have protected my windows account with a password. It is possible to access the data with a Linux-Live-CD? Is the password protection enough?

Comment: Linux doesn't support Bitlocker.  This entirely depends if you configured the drive to automatically mount or not when you login.  It is a trivial task to change the password of a Windows user profile outside of Windows.

Comment: I am using my microsoft account for login. There is no local account configure on the pc. Still a trivial task to change the password of a Windows user profile?

Answer (score 0):

Now, I may be wrong about my answer, and will be willing to delete this answer if someone can point out where I am wrong. However, I've done a bit of research into BitLocker and think this may be correct. So here goes.

If the attacker really wants to access your data, they can take the drive out of the laptop and connect it to another Windows machine as a data drive. Then, using the usb key, they can unlock it with the following command.

```
manage-bde -unlock $mountLetterOrGUID -rk $usbKeyPath
```

On the other hand, if they do not remove the drive, and simply turn on the laptop, they will be greeted with the login screen. In this case, the data is as secure as the login screen (meaning, if they break into your account via the login screen, they will have access to the drive). I'm assuming you are using Windows 8.1 or 10. Since you are using a Internet connected Microsoft Account, it is a bit harder to break into your account. So your only worry resides with the attacker taking out your drive and your usb key and attempting to mount it as a data drive.